# Mostrar vista con contenido variable mvc

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Buen día 
Necesito ayuda en lo siguiente, Estoy trabajando con mvc quiero tener una sección de noticias y que al apretar "Leer más" cargue una vista parcial pero en otra pagina, la cual el contenido sea variable según el link que selecciono, he intentado enviar un id con javascript y recibirlo en en el control, pero no tengo buenos resultado por favor ayúdenme

```
<div>
<h4> Noticias</h4>
<div>
    noticia 1
    <a href="#" id="leerA"><span>Leer más</span></a>
</div>
<div>
    noticia 2
    <a href="#" id="leerB"><span>Leer más</span></a>
</div>
<div>
    noticia 3
    <a href="#" id="leerC"><span>Leer más</span></a>
</div>
```

Asumo que algo así debería tener, para buscar la noticia que necesito pero no logro enviar el código desde la vista de mi pagina principal

```
 public ActionResult Noticias(string codigo)
    {
        ListaNoticias.Find(c => c.Id.Equals(codigo));
        return PartialView("Noticias", noticia);
    }
```

Se agradece cualquier ayuda

Comment: lograste hacerlo funcionar?

Comment: no, deje de lado eso, si me puedes dar una ayuda, te agradecería mucho

Comment: claro, agrega todo el código que mencionas "he intentado enviar un id con javascript y recibirlo en en el control" y lo hacemos funcionar :D

Answer (score 0):

Para estos casos se suele usar los HTMLHELPER que es una clase con métodos en el que construyes un código html para pintarlo en la vista.

[ways to create Custom Html Helper in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.webdevelopmenthelp.net/2014/07/custom-html-helper-in-aspnet-mvc.html)